# How to iteratively remove values so that there are no negative predictions in regression in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Here my data

```
data=structure(list(session_id = c(13532925L, 13532921L, 13532918L, 
13532917L, 13532912L, 13532910L, 13532909L, 13532908L, 13532907L, 
13532900L), weekday_session = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), hour_session = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), session_price = c(18630L, 5410L, 20790L, 5410L, 7780L, 16590L, 
5410L, 9870L, 4190L, 13770L), flight_type = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), airline_id = c(156L, 156L, 156L, 156L, 
238L, 156L, 156L, 238L, 238L, 156L), meta_flight_type = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), days_to_flight = c(15L, 
1L, 31L, 1L, 19L, 3L, 0L, 9L, 41L, 3L), flight_area = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("RU", "w", "W"
), class = "factor"), search_category_id = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("13", "other"), class = "factor"), 
    count_passengers = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L), is_children_session = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L), is_infant_session = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), trip_duration_min = c(525L, 120L, 745L, 
    120L, 280L, 725L, 120L, 140L, 220L, 460L), flight_duration_min = c(400L, 
    120L, 440L, 120L, 280L, 570L, 120L, 140L, 220L, 460L), stopovers = c(1L, 
    0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), prediction = c(0.0556, 
    0.3479, 0.0646, 0.3479, 0.1514, 0.1906, 0.293, 0.3693, 0.1871, 
    0.1319)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

here my code

```
mydat<- read.csv("data.csv", sep=";",dec=",")
View(mydat)
str(mydat)
mydat$session_id<-NULL



#split sample on train and sample
index <- sample(1:nrow(mydat),round(0.70*nrow(mydat)))
train <- mydat[index,]
test <- mydat[-index,]

#build the model
mymodel=lm(prediction~.,data=mydat)
summary(mymodel)
```

in result i get negative values , for exmaple -0,023.but there can be no negative values, even zero cannot be.

how in R to make that it iteratively iterate over and remove values from different columns until  in the forecast results ,will not values less than 0.01?
I.E, it  needs to choose such a values for the beta coefficients so that the result in the equation does not get values less or equal to zero.
Is there way to do it?

Comment: what is your response variable?  Can you give us a little bit more context for the requirement of non-negative predictions? Perhaps you could fit to `log(prediction)` and then exponentiate the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR - Those negative coefficients are not a flaw in your model, they are a feature of your data. Many of your variables have negative correlation with your prediction. Can you explain why you expect or require the model coefficients to be positive given much of the data is negatively correlated to your prediction?**

It sounds like you want to remove rows from your data until the coefficient estimates are all positive. Are you sure you want to do this? Negative coefficients do not necessarily mean that your model will return predicted values less than zero. Before you do this, maybe you should visualize your data and find out what is going on.

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(mydat, aes(x = trip_duration_min, y = prediction)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

[image]

There is a strong negative correlation between your `prediction` label and your `trip_duration_min` variable.

```
cor(mydat$trip_duration_min, mydat$prediction)
[1] -0.7856956
```

To get this correlation to be positive, you would need to remove from your example data set all rows with `trip_duration_min > 400` (more than half of your data). You can do this, but the overall correlation and the overall model are weaker. Your prediction would not be very good.

```
cor(mydat$trip_duration_min[which(mydat$trip_duration_min > 400)], 
    mydat$prediction[which(mydat$trip_duration_min > 400)])
[1] 0.1650505
```

Also, if you remove those rows, you have no guarantee that doing so will have a desirable outcome on the other coefficients:

```
library(dplyr)
mymodel = lm(prediction~., data = mydat %>% filter(trip_duration_min > 400))
summary(mymodel)
Call:
lm(formula = prediction ~ ., data = mydat %>% filter(trip_duration_min > 
    400))

Residuals:
ALL 4 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients: (12 not defined because of singularities)
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)             -1.319e-01         NA      NA       NA
weekday_session                 NA         NA      NA       NA
hour_session                    NA         NA      NA       NA
session_price            2.082e-05         NA      NA       NA
flight_type                     NA         NA      NA       NA
airline_id                      NA         NA      NA       NA
meta_flight_type        -8.600e-02         NA      NA       NA
days_to_flight          -7.622e-03         NA      NA       NA
flight_areaW                    NA         NA      NA       NA
search_category_idother         NA         NA      NA       NA
count_passengers                NA         NA      NA       NA
is_children_session             NA         NA      NA       NA
is_infant_session               NA         NA      NA       NA
trip_duration_min               NA         NA      NA       NA
flight_duration_min             NA         NA      NA       NA
stopovers                       NA         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 3 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

This model generates a lot of `NA` values because the number of rows are so few, but the remaining coefficients are still negative.

Please note that these coefficients do not mean that your predicted values will be negative. If you `predict` your model, you will find that it generates results greater than zero. The fit is exceedingly good, but that is because your example data in your question has fewer observations than variables.

```
predict(mymodel)
     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10 
0.0556 0.3479 0.0646 0.3479 0.1514 0.1906 0.2930 0.3693 0.1871 0.1319
```

Here is a full glimpse at your correlation coefficients of each variable with `prediction`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydat %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)) %>%
  cor %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = "var1") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -var1, names_to = "var2", values_to = "cor") %>%
  filter(var1 != var2,
         !is.na(cor),
         var1 == "prediction") %>%
  arrange(cor)
# A tibble: 13 x 3
   var1       var2                    cor
   <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 prediction trip_duration_min   -0.786 
 2 prediction flight_duration_min -0.781 
 3 prediction session_price       -0.724 
 4 prediction stopovers           -0.646 
 5 prediction days_to_flight      -0.526 
 6 prediction search_category_id  -0.271 
 7 prediction flight_type         -0.186 
 8 prediction flight_area         -0.111 
 9 prediction is_infant_session    0.0369
10 prediction airline_id           0.129 
11 prediction count_passengers     0.287 
12 prediction is_children_session  0.336 
13 prediction meta_flight_type     0.344
```

Only five variables have positive correlation with `prediction`. You could build a model out of only those five. And you will still get negative coefficients in the model.

```
model_2 <- lm(prediction ~ is_infant_session + airline_id + 
              count_passengers + is_children_session + 
              meta_flight_type, data = mydat)
summary(model_2)
Call:
lm(formula = prediction ~ is_infant_session + airline_id + count_passengers + 
    is_children_session + meta_flight_type, data = mydat)

Residuals:
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10 
-1.949e-01  9.743e-02 -3.365e-02  9.743e-02  8.327e-17  4.163e-17 -1.388e-16  9.110e-02 -9.110e-02  3.365e-02 

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         -0.082271   0.346762  -0.237    0.824
is_infant_session   -0.049817   0.231749  -0.215    0.840
airline_id           0.001256   0.003878   0.324    0.762
count_passengers    -0.015367   0.409196  -0.038    0.972
is_children_session  0.092350   0.168622   0.548    0.613
meta_flight_type     0.152217   0.125684   1.211    0.293

Residual standard error: 0.1377 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3961,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.3587 
F-statistic: 0.5248 on 5 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.7522
```

However, when you predict this model, you still get results with positive values.

```
predict(model_2)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
0.2504667 0.2504667 0.0982500 0.2504667 0.1514000 0.1906000 0.2930000 0.2782000 0.2782000 0.0982500
```

Comment: thanks. One question.We see the residuals. For example, it was 0.2 and predicted 0.05, so the residuals is 0.15. Is it possible to make the model look, the residual is 0.15, incorrectly, and remove the values from the variables until the residuals becomes at least 1% of the real value?

Comment: @DataMiner - You could do so, but you run the risk of a model that fits your test data really well but will be a poor predictor of new data.